# Boost Qi Composing rules using Functions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to define some Boost::spirit::qi parsers for multiple subsets of a language with minimal code duplication. To do this, I created a few basic rule building functions. The original parser works fine, but once I started to use the composing functions, my parsers no longer seem to work.

The general language is of the form:

```
A B: C
```

There are subsets of the language where `A`, `B`, or `C` must be specific types, such as `A` is an int while `B` and `C` are floats. Here is the parser I used for that sub language:

```
using entry = boost::tuple<int, float, float>;

template <typename Iterator>
struct sublang : grammar<Iterator, entry(), ascii::space_type>
{
   sublang() : sublang::base_type(start)
   {
       start = int_ >> float_ >> ':' >> float_;
   }
   rule<Iterator, entry(), ascii::space_type> start;
};
```

But since there are many subsets, I tried to create a function to build my parser rules:

```
template<typename AttrName, typename Value>
auto attribute(AttrName attrName, Value value)
{
    return attrName >> ':' >> value;
}
```

So that I could build parsers for each subset more easily without duplicate information:

```
// in sublang
start = int_ >> attribute(float_, float_);
```

This fails however and I'm not sure why. In my clang testing, parsing just fails. In g++, it seems the program crashes.

Here's the full example code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8636f19b2e9bff8d

What is wrong with the current code and what would be the correct approach for this problem? I would like to avoid specifying the grammar of attributes and other elements in each sublanguage parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply: using `auto` with Spirit (or any EDSL based on Boost Proto and Boost Phoenix) is most likely Undefined Behaviour¹

Now, you can usually fix this using

- BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO
- `boost::proto::deep_copy`
- the new facility that's coming in the most recent version of Boost (TODO add link)

In this case,

```
template<typename AttrName, typename Value>
auto attribute(AttrName attrName, Value value) {
    return boost::proto::deep_copy(attrName >> ':' >> value);
}
```

fixes it: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3e9e172a27b0047)</kbd>**

#### Alternatively

1. you could use `qi::lazy[]` with inherited attributes.

   I do very similar things in the `prop_key` rule in [Reading JSON file with C++ and BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746109/reading-json-file-with-c-and-boost/27760376#27760376).
2. you could have a look at the **[Keyword List Operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/operators/keyword_list.html)** from the Spirit Repository. It's designed to allow easier construction of grammars like:

   ```
   no_constraint_person_rule %=
       kwd("name")['=' > parse_string ]
     / kwd("age")   ['=' > int_]
     / kwd("size")   ['=' > double_ > 'm']
     ;
   ```
3. This you could potentially combine with the [Nabialek Trick](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/nabialek-trick/). I'd search the answers on SO for examples. (One is [Grammar balancing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846491/grammar-balancing-issue/20851705#20851705))

---

¹ Except for entirely stateless actors ([Eric Niebler on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144948/static-functions-from-boost-lambda-or-boost-phoenix/12326204#12326204)) and expression placeholders. See e.g.

- [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)
- [undefined behaviour somewhere in boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410498/undefined-behaviour-somewhere-in-boostspiritqiphrase-parse/26411266#26411266)
- [C++ Boost qi recursive rule construction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405500/c-boost-qi-recursive-rule-construction/17408206#17408206)
- [boost spirit V2 qi bug associated with optimization level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763665/boost-spirit-v2-qi-bug-associated-with-optimization-level/20766909#20766909)

Some examples

- [Define parsers parameterized with sub-parsers in Boost Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238381/define-parsers-parameterized-with-sub-parsers-in-boost-spirit/21247178#21247178)
- [Generating Spirit parser expressions from a variadic list of alternative parser expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177184/generating-spirit-parser-expressions-from-a-variadic-list-of-alternative-parser/16181550#16181550)